# jquery use scrollTop within if else condition

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm using an 'if else' w/jquery and am having trouble figuring out how to properly fill in the second (i.e., scrollTop) condition  -

```
$(window).load(function(){  
     if (window.location.hash == '' && $(window).scrollTop() == 0) {

         doStuff_01('');

     } else {
         doStuff_02('');
     }
});
```

This is for an animated page entry. If the user has just showed up there,
it should fire off the anims. But, if the user has already showed up,
scrolled down a little, and hit 'refresh', it should not fire off the
anims.

How do I write:

if window.location.hash == ''

*AND*

'the window has already been scrolled down by at least 1px' <-- this is the one that eludes me.

Should I even be using .scrollTop()?

Answer (score 0):

> the window has already been scrolled down by at least 1px

can be represented in code as

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that .scrollTop is an action, thus, using it as a condition just won't work. I need to find an alternate way of saying, "When the page loads, if the history recalls the page has NOT already been scrolled, go ahead."

Comment: @Greta - `scrollTop ()` is an *action* only when called with an argument. Without arguments it is purely a *getter* that returns the current scroll top value - and can be used in conditions.

Comment: Alright thanks. So this can be used. Why this isn't working is baffling. When you refresh a page, the browser remembers how far you had scrolled down. It doesn't force you back to zero/top.